# Realtime JSON registration on website

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm looking for a way to get user email and make it in realtime. Currently I using JSON to do this, but how I can do it without JSON? Because now on website everyone can see emails which are in `$resEmailsJson;` JSON. Good way would be to hide all JSON `$resEmailsJson;` emails, but from what I found, this is impossible. What should I use to get emails in realtime and check if this email exsist and then display error?

Comment: Unless you use the JS variable like you are currently doing, the option ehich comes to mind is `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your code well, you are fetching all users emails from your database, putting them into your javascript and when the user wants to proceed, you just check if the entered email is already in that array. You should *not* be doing this as javascript is client-side, so the user can see all the emails.
If you want to keep using json, you should have a look at AJAX requests insteed: the user enters it's email, validates, you query a PHP script via AJAX asking if this email is already in the database, the script returns a true/false value, your javascript gets it and then tells the user wether it's email is OK or not.

Hope it helps.